# Execute WikiData query through request promise in Node JS

Tags: node.js, sparql, wikipedia, wiki, wikidata

I'm executing wiki data query using request promise:

```
  var rp= require('request-promise');
  var wdk = require('wikidata-sdk');
  sparql='SELECT ?author ?authorLabel ?authorDescription ?authorAltLabel ?birth WHERE {
        wd:Q1451094 wdt:P50 ?author .
        ?author wdt:P569 ?birth .
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }}' 
 url = wdk.sparqlQuery(sparql);
 rp(url).then(wdk.simplify.sparqlResults).then(function(simplifiedResults) {
 if(!_.isEmpty(simplifiedResults)){
    console.log(simplifiedResults,'-----simplifiedResults');
 }
```

});`

through Node.JS, previously i'd get results, but now i'm getting errors:[image]

Please help with a solution, thanks in advance.